# Blink in custom transition, ios7

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I use this code:

```
    CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc]init];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype= kCATransitionFromLeft;
    //transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransactionCompletionBlock];
```

And get visual blink at right of view. If I use  kCATransitionFromRight I get blink at the left. I tested in simulator and on device. That is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the bellow code and follow bellow instructions

```
  CATransition *navTransition = [CATransition animation];
    navTransition.duration = 0.65;
    navTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction 
          functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [navTransition setType:kCATransitionReveal];
    [navTransition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [view.navigationController.navigationBar.layer 
          addAnimation:navTransition forKey:nil];
```

Here's a best  way:

Create a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` for your `UINavigationController`. You'll get to hear about new views being pushed/popped onto the nav stack via one of the delegate methods such as `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`. In the appropriate delegate method you can set a property on your custom `UIViewController` so that it knows which animation to use in `viewWillAppear` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If deploy target is 7.0, use UINavigationControllerDelegate to customize push/pop animation.

It's little bit complicated, but it's very powerful. Whatever you imagine, you can do with these delegates.

```
- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                      interactionControllerForAnimationController:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>) animationController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                               animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                            fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                              toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```